# Cannot select flash object jQuery swfobject

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I'm using `swfobject` to embed flash object but after it's rendered,

Below code doesn't seem to select the flash object at all it just picks up the div element that was there before it is being rendered:

```
flashMovie = document.getElementById("slideshare-player");
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You want the **'object'** inside your div.

**//get the ID of your swf**

```
swfName = document.getElementById("slideshare-player").getElementsByTagName('object')[0].id;
```

**//get the object**

```
flashMovie = document.getElementById(swfName);
```

**//tell it to do something**

```
flashMovie.doSomeStuff();
```